# Qual a diferença entre as opções facet_wrap() e facet_grid() no ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As opções `facet_wrap()` e `facet_grid()` no `ggplot` têm propósitos semelhantes, produzir gráficos com resultados estratificados por uma variável categórica. No entanto, às vezes essas opções produzem resultados esteticamente idênticos, às vezes semelhantes, às vezes muito diferentes.

Qual é a diferença de racionalidade por traz dessas duas opções? Há algum critério para escolher uma das duas?

**Exemplo de resultado idêntico:**

```
library(ggplot2)

g1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_point()

g1 + facet_wrap(~ Species)

g1 + facet_grid(~ Species)
```

**Exemplo de resultado similar:**

```
g2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point()

g2 + facet_wrap(~cyl)

g2 + facet_grid(~cyl)
```

**Exemplo de resultado diferente:**

```
g2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point()

g2 + facet_wrap(cyl~class)

g2 + facet_grid(cyl~class)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Qual é a diferença de racionalidade por traz dessas duas opções?

`facet_wrap` transforma uma sequência de uma dimensão de painéis em algo em duas dimensões, enquanto `facet_grid` cria uma matriz de painéis. Usando os exemplos da pergunta, temos

```
library(ggplot2)

g2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
    geom_point()

g2 + facet_wrap(cyl~class)
```

[image]

```
g2 + facet_grid(cyl~class)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note que, ao usar `facet_wrap`, as combinações entre `cyl` e `class` são colocadas juntas, no título de cada painel, de modo que eles poderiam estar enfileirados, em uma dimensão, sem problema algum de identificação de qual é cada painel.

Por outro lado, ao usar `facet_grid`, é criada uma matriz de painéis com todas as combinações de níveis das variáveis categóricas consideradas. Perceba que há mais painéis com `facet_grid` do que com `facet_wrap`, mas esses painéis extras estão vazios.

Por esse motivo, na imensa maioria das vezes, não faz diferença usar `facet_wrap` ou `facet_grid` se apenas uma variável categórica for utilizada para criar os painéis.

> Há algum critério para escolher uma das duas?

Tirando alguma preferência estética, não vejo porque optar por uma ou por outra. Ambas exibem a mesma informação, embora eu prefira o resultado de `facet_grid` quando há informações para exibir em todas as combinações possíveis. Caso contrário, uso `facet_wrap` para economizar espaço, descartando automaticamente os casos que não ocorrem.